# Custom layout and gravity of TextView (horizontal gravity works but vertical fails)

Tags: android, textview, gravity

We have encountered a problem with the following `View`. The `TextView`'s gravity should center its text horizontally and vertically, but the text is just centered horizontally and sticks at the top. What's wrong?

```
public class TestLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private TextView textView;

    public TestLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Hello world.");
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        addView(textView);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        textView.layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have found the solution. We need to call `measure()` on the children of the layout.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: God bless you!!